# .htaccess redirect file-type or files within directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can't figure out how to use .htaccess to redirect when any file is accessed within a directory, or, how to redirect when a specific file type (eg. .txt or .php) is accessed.

I've got a directory called "contents" where I'm storing .txt files, these are pulled into the main page using php.  However, I don't want users to be able to access the specific text files where the contents are, eg. going directly to .../contents/textfile.txt.  I'd like if a user happened on a .txt file, or any file within the contents directory, to be redirected to the root site.

If this isn't the right approach, please let me know what would be so I can search to attack it from another way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to lock the directory down, so that users are informed that it's an invalid directory. Create a .htaccess file in the contents-directory with the following text:

`deny from all`

If you want a redirect, you should investigate "mod_rewrite" - a module that is installed on many webhosts. It will probably be something similar to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^.+  http://www.example.com/  [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks @Optimist, closer to what I need. I would rather avoid `deny from all` as that just make it look a little strange to a user, the best solution (in my opinion) would be one that brings them back to the root, I think that the rewrite rule that you've provided will do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the [Deny Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#deny)

add,

```
Order Deny,Allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

into a `.htaccess` and place it in `contents` directory.